# How do you derive a loop invariant from a function?

Tags: proof-of-correctness

What is the loop invariant of this function and how do you derive it from the function?

I've been reading up on algorithms to prepare myself for further studies but am unable to understand how to derive loop invariants.

```
function maxint(a)
b = 1
c = 1

while b != a
    c = c * 2 + 1
    b = b + 1
end while

return c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Loop invariants are variables, conditions, etc. that don't change throughout the loop. The point of finding invariants is to figure which ones don't need to be recomputed/reloaded/reestablished every time they're accessed/assumed in a loop.</strike>

Invariant values are those that don't change throughout the loop, Invariant conditions, on the other hand, are usually more about correctness, like making sure a different thread isn't modifying a data structure that the loop is traversing. At that point, however, you might say that *invariant* is a bit of an overloaded term. In this context it seems that you are just after the invariant values.

Therefore, if you are looking for the loop invariant values, they would be `a`, `2`, `1`, and the second `1`.

**EDIT:**

I see now that this isn't a practical programming question; it's a computer science question that probably belongs on the CS SE. That being said, I think I can help. Step 1 on [this](http://www-inst.cs.berkeley.edu/~cs170/fa14/tutorials/tutorial1.pdf) site is where you should start.

To summarize:

1. Transform the loop into the more familiar `for` loop.
2. Run a few iterations manually.
3. Try to find a pattern that gives you a formula for the return value that isn't recursively defined in terms of the return value. You want it to depend only on the current iteration count and other variables/values used in the loop.

## Step 1

Notice that the code can be transformed into the following `for` loop:

```
c = 1
for (b = 1; b <= a; b = b + 1)
    c = c * 2 + 1
end for
```

Now, we can see that `b` is just the loop variable, and `a` is the loop bound. To make things clearer, we can write it as a more traditional c-style `for` loop:

```
c = 1;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    c = c * 2 + 1;
}
```

## Step 2

```
i_0: c =     ?      = 1 // Don't forget the initial value! Call that iteration 0.
i_1: c = 1  * 2 + 1 = 3
i_2: c = 3  * 2 + 1 = 7
i_3: c = 7  * 2 + 1 = 15
i_4: c = 15 * 2 + 1 = 63
```

## Step 3

Look for a pattern in that relates the output variable, `c`, to the current iteration, `i`.

Note that `i` in this context refers to the current iteration of the loop, not the value of the variable `i` in the code.

Notice that a power-of-2 pattern emerges: `c_i = 2^(i+1) - 1`.

There may in fact more than one that emerges. How do we know if this one works? That's what the base iteration and inductive step are for.

Plugging `0` in for the iteration gives us `c_0 = 2^(0+1)-1 = 2-1 = 1`, which gives us the starting value for `c`, so that's good.

For the inductive step, we need to show that `c_(i+1) = 2^(i+2) - 1`. Problem is, we can't just say that and call it a day. We need something else that `c_(i+1)` equals.

Fortunately, that's exactly what the code gives us, a formula for computing a new value of `c` given the one from the previous iteration: `c = c * 2 + 1`, which written formally looks like:

`c_(i+1) = c_i * 2 + 1`.

We assume that our invariant is correct, and plug it in for `c_i`. Then, we set the whole thing equal to `2^(i+2) - 1`:

`c_(i+1) = (2^(i+1) - 1) * 2 + 1 = 2^(i+2) - 1`.

`(2^(i+1) - 1) * 2 + 1 = 2*2^(i+1) - 2 + 1 = 2^(i+2) - 1`

We satisfied the base case and the inductive step, so we know our invariant is correct. We've also shown that, since the loop terminates on iteration 
`n`, `c = 2^(n+1) - 1`.

## TL;DR

Substituting in the original variables:

Loop invariant: `c = 2^(b+1) - 1`.
`maxint(a)`: `2^(a+1) - 1`

Comment: in that sense, how do you go about formatting the loop invariant?

Comment: @Ryan27 What do you mean by formatting? Formalizing in some academic sense? If so, then I'm not sure. You would need to point me to some examples that you are looking at. My understanding is purely practical.

Comment: @Ryan27 I understand your question now. See my edit.

Comment: Hi, yes i meant academic sense, sorry if I im in the wrong forum. Your answer really helps, thanks !